# Using a for statement to create variables from array

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, for-loop

I have a set of numbers that I need to pass from a function to a few other functions before it is actually used.  I figured an array is a good way to do this, however I can't remember how to do what I want to do.  The code looks like this

```
int set1; // variables that hold settings
int set2;
int set3;
cout << "Setting 1";
cin >> set1;
cout << "Setting 2";
cin >> set2;
cout << "Setting 3";
cin >> set3;
int settings[3] = {set1, set2, set3}; //array that holds variables
```

so that is how the array is created.
However what I am hoping is to be able to do something like this, I know some languages can ( I am pretty sure), but I don't know if C++ can, or what this method is even called (so I can't google it)

```
int setting0;
int setting1;
int setting2;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
          setting+i = setting[i]; // should set setting0 = setting[0]; etc
    }
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I know that the for loop is wrong, but that is what I am hoping to fix.

Comment: Variables names are a compile-time construct, they don't exist at runtime. Your best bet is to make `setting0-2` an array, `setting[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the functions you're calling need to change the array content, Change your array decl to this:

```
int *(settings[3]) = {&set1, &set2, &set3}; //array that holds pointers to variables
```

Then change your loop to:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
 *(settings[i]) = setting[i]; // should set set1 = setting[0]; etc
}
```

Not sure if I understood your question quite right...

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this without initially using an array (i.e., `int set[3]`), or doing something more complicated than your first example.

Of course, you can rewrite your code, such as

```
int settings[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    cout << "Setting " << i+1;
    cin >> settings[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference variables from a name computed at runtime like that in C++. Your options are either to pass the array itself directly to the function in question (this is probably the best approach) or to bind the variables manually at compile time:

```
// NOTE - this is ALMOST ALWAYS not the right thing to do!
int setting0 = setting[0];
int setting1 = setting[1];
int setting2 = setting[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong approach. If you are passing an array, why not use the values in the array?

Like, instead of

```
printf("Hello %s",setting3);
```

do

```
printf("Hello %s",setting[3]);
```

or if you want to be fancy and use an associative array

```
printf("Hello %s",setting['first_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was a dumb question, I need to take a break.  What I will do is 
set all the 
cin >> setting[0]; etc.  I don't know what I was thinking, can I unask, lol.